# How to play mono audio ONLY when NOT plugged in headphone in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, headphones, mono

My laptop's right speaker has broken, so I want to play mono audio when using internal speakers. In windows 10 there is an option to turn on mono audio in setting. But it makes my headphone, which is working fine, to play mono audio as well. 
How do I turn on mono audio when using laptop's internal speakers and turn off (back to stereo) when headphone is plugged in (without changing the setting every time)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Audio Virtual Cable](https://www.vb-audio.com/index.htm) for this.

- Install [VB-CABLE Driver](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm) and [Voicemeeter](https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/index.htm).
- In Windows Audio settings set VoiceMeeter Input as default Output device.
- In Voicemeeter set Hardware out 1 as Speakers and Hardware out 2 as headphones.
- Click Mono button under big A letter to set Hardware out 1 to mono.